# Может(,) мы зря всё это устроили?

Tags: пунктуация

Ставится ли запятая "Может(,) мы зря всё это устроили?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Gramota.ru" отмечает, что "может" в такой ситуации - вводное слово, подобное "вероятно", "возможно" и "может быть", и оделяется запятой.

Больше [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_416).

Answer (score 0):

Слово *может* является вводным, и его необходимо выделять запятыми. Бывают случаи, когда оно является членом предложения, например: *Моя мама может пойти с тобой* (вспомогательный глагол).